# RHEL 7.4 update breaks FileZilla SFTP

Tags: rhel, sftp, filezilla

After updating several of my web servers last night we are now unable to connect to them with FileZilla SFTP client.  Here's the FileZilla log:

```
2017-08-09 16:26:54 7294 3 Status: Connecting to my.rhel74.server...
2017-08-09 16:26:54 7294 3 Response: fzSftp started
2017-08-09 16:26:54 7294 3 Command: keyfile "/home/acoder/.ssh/fz"
2017-08-09 16:26:54 7294 3 Command: open "acoder@my.rhel74.server" 22
2017-08-09 16:26:54 7294 3 Error: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
2017-08-09 16:26:54 7294 3 Error: Could not connect to server
2017-08-09 16:26:54 7294 3 Status: Waiting to retry...
2017-08-09 16:26:59 7294 3 Status: Connecting to my.rhel74.server...
2017-08-09 16:26:59 7294 3 Response: fzSftp started
2017-08-09 16:26:59 7294 3 Command: keyfile "/home/acoder/.ssh/fz"
2017-08-09 16:26:59 7294 3 Command: open "acoder@my.rhel74.server" 22
2017-08-09 16:27:00 7294 3 Error: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
2017-08-09 16:27:00 7294 3 Error: Could not connect to server
```

Checking the server's error log I find:

> Aug  9 17:05:45 rhel74server sshd[5278]: FIPS mode initialized
>
> Aug  9 17:05:45 rhel74server sshd[5278]: fatal: no matching mac found: client
>   hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5 server hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
>   [preauth]

Here is the server's ssh config:

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Protocol 2
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
Ciphers aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
MACs hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
```

We are required to run those Ciphers and MACs, so changing or adding any is problematic.  The above config worked OK until the server OS was updated from RHEL 7.3 to 7.4 a day ago.

Here are the MACs my local system uses:

```
user@linux-mint ~ $ nmap --script ssh2-enum-algos -sV -p 22 rhel74server

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-08-10 14:42 EDT
Nmap scan report for rhel74server (170.140.203.50)
Host is up (0.0026s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 7.4 (protocol 2.0)
| ssh2-enum-algos: 
|   kex_algorithms (1)
|       diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
|   server_host_key_algorithms (3)
|       ssh-rsa
|       rsa-sha2-512
|       rsa-sha2-256
|   encryption_algorithms (3)
|       aes256-ctr
|       aes192-ctr
|       aes128-ctr
|   mac_algorithms (2)
|       hmac-sha2-512
|       hmac-sha2-256
|   compression_algorithms (2)
|       none
|_      zlib@openssh.com

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.38 seconds
user@linux-mint ~ $
```

The server MACs in use are `hmac-sha2-512` and `hmac-sha2-256`, which matches what the client OS is using.

Filezilla appears to ignore what my client OS has configured and is sending the following MACs to the server:

```
fatal: no matching mac found: client
hmac-sha1,
hmac-sha1-96,
hmac-md5
```

I'm on the latest build of FileZilla (3.27.0.1).

Any clues on what else I might try to get this working again?

Comment: Do you have backup's of the config? Cross check the backup configs, of they are all same, check the changelogs. If that does not seem to have an answer. Submit a bug?

Comment: No changes to uncommented lines.  The version info changed at the top but nothing else was pulled form the new file.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated feature due to its inherent lack of security !

In your example, can see that the client is offering:

- hmac-sha1
- hmac-sha1-96
- hmac-md5

But your server is only offering

- hmac-sha2-512
- hmac-sha2-256

So no match found.  Likely that prior to upgrade the server happily offered hmac-sha1.

---

- [What is new in OpenSSH 7.4 (in RHEL 7.4)?](https://access.redhat.com/blogs/766093/posts/3051)

> Deprecation of insecure algorithms
>
> Following up with Deprecation of Insecure Algorithms in RHEL 6.9, legacy algorithms that potentially pose a more serious threats to deployments are being disabled. That, in RHEL 7.4, affects the RC4 ciphers, as well as MD5, RIPE-MD160, and truncated SHA-1 MACs on both client and server side. The ciphers Blowfish, Cast128, and 3DES were removed from the default set of algorithms accepted by the client but are still supported in the server.
>
> If these algorithms are still needed for interoperability with legacy servers or clients, they can be enabled on a per-host basis as described in the upstream documentation. The following example describes how to enable 3des-cbc cipher in a client:
>
> ```
> Host legacy.example.org
>   Ciphers +3des-cbc
> ```
>
> Another example, enabling hmac-md5 in a server for legacy.example.org client:
>
> ```
> Match Host legacy.example.org
>   MACs +hmac-md5
> ```

Comment: My server's sshd Ciphers and MACs config is above.  We do not use SHA-1 and I'm not seeing Blowfish, Cast128 or 3DES in my server's config.  

Is there something I am overlooking in your answer to my question?

Comment: I actually have backups of the sshd_config before the 7.4 update.  `hmac-sha1` is not there.  I removed all `sha1` ciphers and macs a year ago.  Filezilla was working fine with 7.3 with the ciphers and macs in my question.

Comment: I hate to give downvotes, but have to based on this erroneous information:  `Likely that prior to upgrade the server happily offered hmac-sha1.`

Comment: Were you in FIPS mode prior to upgrade ?

Comment: Yes.  I've run FIPS since we updated to RHEL 7.1 over 2 years ago.

Comment: Could it be that you changed your configuration in sshd_config, but did not restart the sshd service ever since? Your filezilla looks like very outdated or badly configured since it is offering only these ancient MACs. If you had this configuration before, there was nothing changed by this update. If you want to verify it, just downgrade the package and verify it will not work either.